# I can't compress a new extension for chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When I try to compress an extension I'm creating for Google Chrome, I get the message below (in portuguese, can't find it in English):

**Erro de extensão de pacote** (Pack extension error)

**Falha ao emitir a chave privada.** (Failed to output private key)

I can "Load unpacked" and run it perfectly..

Code bellow:

**popup.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='./jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='./scripts.js'></script>
</html>
```

**scripts.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('.LoginScreen').length > 0) {
        $("#username").val("usuarioteste");
        $("#password").val("senhateste");
        $("form[name='loginForm'] .DwtButton").click();
    }
});
```

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "name": "Auto Complete Zimbra",
    "version": "1.1",
    "description": "Extensão para autocompletar e logar automaticamente no Zimbra!",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "favicon.ico",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "*://*.meusite.com.br/*"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "*://*.meusite.com.br/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "jquery.min.js",
                "scripts.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Judging by the [source code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/extensions/browser/extension_creator.cc?type=cs&q=IDS_EXTENSION_PRIVATE_KEY_FAILED_TO_OUTPUT&l=178) it means your key file is empty or you've specified the wrong path or the output directory isn't writable.

Comment: Where's this key file? The path i already re-checked and it's right.

Comment: The "Pack extension" dialog takes an "Extension root directory" and a "Private key file (optional)". What are you putting in there?

Comment: "C:\extensao" on the Path input. And letting the optional empty. If i put anything it will appear "The value entered for the private key must be a valid path".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome tries to create a private key file adjacent to the extension directory. In your case that would be `C:\extensao.pem` (and the extension itself wants to go to `C:\extensao.crx`). The default permissions on Windows allow creating directories but not files at the root of the C drive.

Move your extension folder somewhere else.